# C# Selenium Webdriver (Firefox) iFrame does not allow text to be entered via sendKeys

Tags: selenium, iframe

I'm using latest Selenium Firefox (2.53.0)
Previously code was working when performing the following

1) Finding the iFrame by Xpath iframe class

```
IWebElement detailFrame =      `Driver_Lib.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset']"));`
```

2) Switching to that frame by

```
Driver_Lib.Instance.SwitchTo().Frame(detailFrame);
```

3) finding the p tag within the iFrame by

```
IWebElement freeText = Driver_Lib.Instance.FindElement(By.TagName("p"));
```

4) Inserting a simple string to the iframe text box

```
freeText.SendKeys("this is some text");
```

5) switching from the iFrame back to the main contentwindow by

```
Driver_Lib.Instance.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Here is the code part from the application

```
<iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_PageContent_mlcEditor_CKEditor" aria-describedby="cke_61" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title data-cke-title="Rich Text Editor, ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_PageContent_mlcEditor_CKEditor">Rich Text Editor, ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_PageContent_mlcEditor_CKEditor</title>
<style data-cke-temp="1">
<link href="https://myUrl/contents.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style data-cke-temp="1">
</head>
<body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
<p>

<br _moz_editor_bogus_node="TRUE">
</p>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

The test I am running is a simple one, open up that page, insert some text, save.

It not inserting the text into the iFrame.  I am totally puzzled as to why.

Has anyone else found this issue at all?

Many thanks

I have removed the exception, this was a redHerring.

the iFrame can not have text entered into it

Comment: did you getting any exceptions?

Comment: The locator from your exception doesn't match the locator in your example.  Please update your question.

Comment: the exception listed is a red herring so I've removed it.  Why it was throwing this exception was this:  1) the iFrame could not have text entered into it.  2) a next button is then click after text should have been entered. 3) application's validation stated that the iFrame text is mandatory, however we are on a new page now and the exception thrown was relating to a buttonID from the page that should have allowed the save.  The error is relating to not being able to enter text into the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

hi all  I've found the solution:~  here is the summary of what was happening:

1) The iFrame was being located by xPath.

2) the SwitchTo() method used placed focus in the detailFrame instance of IWebElement

3) What was not happening was the p tag could not be located as it was contained withing a CSS Body Class that.

The solution was staring me in the face the whole time!  so simple!!

I did this:

```
IWebElement detailFrame = Driver_Lib.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset']"));         

           Driver_Lib.Instance.SwitchTo().Frame(detailFrame);

           IWebElement freeText = Driver_Lib.Instance.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));             


           freeText.SendKeys("This is a free text question created by Automation Smoke Test");

            Driver_Lib.Instance.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

So as you see, simply locating the 1st instance of the body tag!